# Python Subprocess not working on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Can anyone explain what's happening here? Even built in cmd.exe commands aren't working:

```
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('dir')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 535, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `'dir'`, you have to pass `shell=True`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
```

You have to do this because `dir` is built into the shell itself, it's not a standalone console application. This is also mentioned in the `subprocess.Popen` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies
>   the default shell. **The only time you need to specify shell=True on
>   Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the
>   shell (e.g. dir or copy)**. You do not need shell=True to run a batch
>   file or console-based executable.